# Android development - file permissions denied despite getting user permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

Me and a partner are in the process of developing an android app that opens and modifies a video file. We've tried for a few hours to get the app to open an example file, but are failing to get permissions working. We use the following code to prompt the user for read/write permission:

```
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 2);
        Log.e("###################: ", "WRITE EXTERNAL");
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 3);
        Log.e("###################: ", "READ EXTERNAL");
    }
```

This successfully causes the permission prompt to appear in the app, but even after granting permission we cannot read or write to the file. We know this from testing the permission with this code:

```
    File vidsrc = new File(videopath);

    if (vidsrc.canRead()){
        Log.e("##########: ", "CAN READ VIDEO");
    }
    if (vidsrc.canWrite()){
        Log.e("##########: ", "CAN Write VIDEO");
    }
```

Both of these if statements even after the user grants permission

We also tested to make sure the file path is correct using `vidsrc.exists()` which returns true. Here is our manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*****">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "We use the following code to prompt the user for read/write permission" -- I recommend doing those in a single `requestPermissions()` call. "we get a permission denied error when the app attempts to open the file" -- can you edit the question and provide the complete stack trace? "We know this from testing the permission with this code" -- where is `videopath` coming from?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry, I was incorrect in the original post. We do not get an error when we try to open the file. We can successfully create the file object, but we still do not have read or write permissions. ```videopath``` is a string we hardcoded in with a path to our test video file. I will edit the original post to be more accurate

Comment: "Both of these if statements even after the user grants permission" -- I recommend that you try just reading and writing, rather than attempting to use those methods.

Comment: `videopath is a string we hardcoded in with a path to our test video file` You should in your code assign that value to that variable as you did not tell which path you use. And we have to know. Further your device is Android 10 i think.

Comment: `We do not get an error when we try to open the file. We can successfully create the file object, ` Creating a File object does not open the file. It says nothing about permissions either.